# How can I make AngularJS filter on a nested property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some data where one iteration of it looks like this:

```
{"createDate":"2014-04-22T08:14:10.285Z",
 "desc":"Hej hej",
 "gradeFrom":"4",
 "gradeTo":"7",
 "owner":"martin@forsstedt.com",
 "schoolType":{
     "name":"Grundskola"
  },
 "subject":{ 
     "En":false,
     "Ge":false,
     "Re":true,
     "Sh":false,
     "SvA":false,
     "Tn":false
  },
 "title":"Testing testing"}
```

What I'm trying to do is when a user clicks a button, which populates `$scope.searchText`with "Re":true, only the "iterations" with "subject": {"Re":true) in it should be displayed.

I'm using filtering with a search string which works fine, but it doesn't filter thru the "subject" only the first layer of properties like "createDate", "desc" and so on.

```
<tr ng-repeat="lesson in lessons | orderByPriority | filter:searchText | orderBy:'createDate':true">
```

Comment: How about a custom filter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just populate the `$scope.searchText.subject.RE = true` , the filter does the rest.